# Mongodb set variable to find().toarray()

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, mongodb, express

I'm having trouble getting the following to work

```
var data = db.collection('mycollection', function(er, collection) {
                return collection.find().toArray();
           });
```

The resulting `data` is not an array. I don't get what's wrong. How do I set a varaible to the contents of `find().toArray()`?

I've tried logging the contents like this so I know that there must be data:

```
db.collection('mycollection', function(er, collection) {
   collection.find().toArray(function(err, results) {
       for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
           console.log(results[i]);
       }
   });
});
```

Thanks! I'm very new to ajax programming and mongodb.

Comment: This is basically a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Answer (score 0):

Just go it like in simple way:-

`.find` method always provide data in `array` format.

```
var query = db.collection.find({},function(err,data){

if(err) throw err;

console.log(data); // give in array.
})
```

thanks